# SharePoint Visual Studio solution not visible in solution gallery

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2013, solution

I am trying to locate my solution (WSP) in the solution gallery of SharePoint 2013

- I am site collection administrator
- in Visual Studio I created a solution containing lots of stuff, all works ok, shows up etc.. 
  (deployed via VS and works, site url = site collection root url)
- However... I look in the solution gallery of SP2013 (site collection) and dont see the solution, its 
  actually... empty,

so.. since it has been deployed, activated and works... where is it?

Comment: Is your solution sandboxed or farm?

Comment: farm (and the related feature IS in the list of site collection features)

Comment: Farm solutions are not located in Site Collections solutions gallery. They are located in farm solutions gallery. You can find it in Central Administration -> System Settings -> Farm solutions.

Comment: ah stupid me I realize that now, i was look earlier at farm level solution gallery (empty) but ofcourse these are solution for central admin not the farm solutions, it's late...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Farm solutions are displayed in the Central admin site. Even though in Visual Studio you target your WSP to be deployed in a certain web-site, all WSP's(solutions) available in the farm level are displayed at Central Admin. In this way, if you want to deploy the same solution to a different web application you could do it from central admin. It actually makes the work easy.

So, It's not displayed in the web application which you deployed to. Please check on the central admin site.

Go to central admin > System settings > Under "Farm Management" you get "Manage Farm Solutions". All the farm solutions will be listed down there.